# Require theme with a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have created an elementor widgets plugin for my theme and now want to package my theme with my plugin. Like if a user installed an individual plugin without my theme then will throw the error 'Require my theme'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the name of the active (parent) theme and throw a notice if it doesn't match with your theme. And set i.e. a link to the download page.

[image: WP Admin Theme Notice]

Put the code into your main plugin file:

```
function check_my_theme() {
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $my_theme_name = 'My Theme'; // Edit Theme name.
    if( $theme->name != $my_theme_name && $theme->parent_theme != $my_theme_name ) {
        $class = 'notice notice-error';
        $message = __( 'You are using the wrong Theme. Take instead ', 'your-plugin' );
        $link_to_theme = '#'; // Edit link to theme.

        printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s<a href="%3$s" target="_blank">%4$s</a></p></div>',
               esc_attr( $class ),
               esc_html( $message ),
               esc_url( $link_to_theme ),
               esc_html( $my_theme_name )
        );      
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'check_my_theme');
```